# como acessar o nome de um objeto apenas

Tags: javascript, array, json

Olá! Boa tarde! Não estou conseguindo obter apenas o nome de um objeto dentro de outro objeto que esta dentro de um array:
`[ { "name": { "common": "Finland", "official": "Republic of Finland", "nativeName": { "fin": { "official": "Suomen tasavalta", "common": "Suomi" }, "swe": { "official": "Republiken Finland", "common": "Finland" } } }, "tld": [ ".fi" ], "cca2": "FI", "ccn3": "246", "cca3": "FIN", "cioc": "FIN", "independent": true, "status": "officially-assigned", "unMember": true, *"currencies": { "EUR": { "name": "Euro", "symbol": "€" } },`*

No caso esse é o array, preciso acessar o currencies e pegar apenas a abreviação como no caso anterior "EUR", que acaba sendo outro objeto.

Comment: Essa abreviação muda? Tipo, nesse caso a currency é EUR, mas poderia ser BRL ou outra moeda?

Comment: Sim, isso e parte do retorno de uma API com os dados de todos os paises do mundo. https://restcountries.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Juan, nessa situação, você consegue obter o nome de uma propriedade utilizando um `Object.keys()`, que retorna o nome das suas chaves. No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
const info = [
  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Finland",
      "official": "Republic of Finland",
      "nativeName": {
        "fin": {
          "official": "Suomen tasavalta",
          "common": "Suomi"
        },
        "swe": {
          "official": "Republiken Finland",
          "common": "Finland"
        }
      }
    },
    "tld": [".fi"],
    "cca2": "FI",
    "ccn3": "246",
    "cca3": "FIN",
    "cioc": "FIN",
    "independent": true,
    "status": "officially-assigned",
    "unMember": true,
    "currencies": {
      "EUR": {
        "name": "Euro",
        "symbol": "€"
      }
    }
  }
]
const infoCurrency = info[0]['currencies']
const currencies = Object.keys(infoCurrency)
console.log(currencies);
//[ 'EUR' ]
```

Ai isso seria uma lista com o nome das chaves, ai você consegue pegar o primeiro elemento dessa lista ('EUR') usando um `currencies[0]`